# CSS transition fades, then disappears

Tags: html, css

In [this example version of my code](http://codepen.io/notionparallax/pen/bhorm) if you hover over one of the non-faded faces some text appears over it for the duration of the transition and then disappears. If you do the same thing over one of the *faded* faces the text appears over it for the duration of the transition and then seems to jump to behind everything.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dx2d2G9pXb8

I have tried altering the z-index of all the elements involved but it seems to have no effect. How do I make it fade from invisible to visible, and then stay there?

This is a cut down version of the important scss

```
.value-tweet-container {
    z-index: 2000;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
         -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
            transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
    &:hover{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the overlay to stay, add `position: absolute` and `top: 0` / `left: 0`.

Like this:

```
.value-tweet-container {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Remove if you don't want to cover the entire tile */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%; /* Remove if you don't want to cover the entire tile */
  width: 100%; /* Remove if you don't want to cover the entire tile */
}
```

[Here is your new pen.](http://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/syibu)

The `border-box` helps as it adds the padding into the height and width percentage calculation and I removed the 3px margin.

If you **don't** want the tile to be covered by the overlay, remove the lines where indicated.